# Shifting Column Selection in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements, cbind

I have a data frame with 30 columns. My goal is to select 5 columns at a time. Based on a condition, I want to shift my selection in the data frame 5 columns.

For example:

Original dataframe column selection:

```
Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Col10
```

If condition is true, select:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
```

If condition is false, select:

```
Col11 Col12 Col13 Col14 Col15.
```

I don't want to call out those specific columns though, I want to write a general formula that would call out a shift of 5 columns to the right or left based on whether the condition was true or false.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please share example data.

Comment: So, you are only selecting columns 1:5 and 11:15 based on the condition?

Comment: I can't but I basically just want to shift my selection a specific ncolumns to the right or left from my starting column selection point.

Comment: @akrun I'm not starting with those columns specifically, I just want to know if there is a function that can shift my column selection a number of columns to the left of right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you asked I developed the following code. Please clarify the question if this is not what you are looking for. Assuming that your data frame is `df`:

```
n <- 1

df[,n:n+4]

if (condition){
  n <- n + 5
} else if (condition && n != 1) {
  n <- n - 5
}
```

Comment: @Nick If this answer was what you were expecting, would you mind accepting it as correct? Thanks

Comment: I'm new to this, how do I do that?

Comment: Just click the check mark on the left side of the answer.